# How to pass partial form's data to Rails action (with javascript & without nested attributes)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a from to invite new users to sign up to my app. Only signed-up users can invite new users. Invited users will receive invitation email from signed up user.

I got stucked when trying to add dynamic email input field. I'm able to add another field with jQuery help but I've no idea how to pass all `email` input data to my `send_email` action inside users_controller.rb file.

I'm not planning to use [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) because I'm not saving anything to database.

**app/views/users/add_users.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag(send_email_path, method: :post) do %>
    <span id="fields">
        <%= render "new_user" %>
    </span>
    <%= button_tag(type: 'button', id: "addBtn") do %>Add<% end %>
<% end %>

<script>
    $("#addBtn").click(function(){
        $("#fields").append("<br/><%= j render 'new_user' %>");
    });
</script>
```

**app/views/users/_new_user.html.erb**

```
<label>User</label>
<br>
<%= email_field_tag 'email', nil, class: 'email-input', id: "email-input" %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def send_email

    AddUserMailer.sign_up_email(current_user, params[:email]).deliver_now
    redirect_to '/'

end
```

**app/mailers/add_user_mailer.rb**

```
class AddUserMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: 'example@example.com'

    def sign_up_email(user, address)
        @url = "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up?sc=#{user.customer.secret_code}&cust=#{user.customer.id}"
        mail(to: address, subject: "Sign up")
    end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'add_users' => "users#add_users"
post 'send_email' => "users#send_email"
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the params that are generated in the server logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `app/views/users/_new_user.html.erb` file to the following contents:

```
<label>User</label>
<br>
<%= email_field_tag 'email[]', nil, class: 'email-input', id: "email-input" %>
```

Notice that the first argument of `email_field_tag` (the name of the input field) has changed from `email` to `email[]`. This is a Rails' convention that will set `params[:email]` to an array.

You can then modify `users_controller.rb` to something like this:

```
def send_email
  params[:email].each do |email_address|
    AddUserMailer.sign_up_email(current_user, email_address).deliver_now
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```